# I have created non-admin user but its not loading any databases what can be the reason behind this?

Tags: couchdb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L4Vk.png) After creating the non-admin user I have set permission for a specific database as well but when I log in with a non-admin user its shows a loading database and doesn't show anything and other nodes also don't get loaded.

Comment: Could you add more info to this question?. With the current detail it is very difficult to propose a solution. Also, you have opened other questions and it seems that some answers are helping you to going forward. It could be great if you can give some feedback on those questions, It may be helpful for others.

Comment: ok got it Juanjo Rodriguez

Comment: @sandeshJadhav : Any chance you resolved this ? I'm in the same situation... :/

Comment: Had the same problem, just wanted to view the contents so went straight to this url: `http://localhost:5984/_utils/#/database/my-db-name/_all_docs`

Answer (score 1):

I found the explanation [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/266298/262084)

> In CouchDB 3.0.0, the /_all_dbs endpoint became admin-only. This has the side-effect of Fauxton, the “Browser GUI”, not loading properly for non-admin users, as it starts out by reading /_all_dbs.
>
> The [release notes](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/whatsnew/3.0.html#upgrade-notes) have a section that go into the changes.
>
> This is the code change: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2576
>
> You can get the previous behaviour by setting the config variable [chttpd] admin_only_all_dbs to false, but that allows even unauthenticated users to get a full list of your databases.